# Start docker multicontainer on Elastic Beanstalk with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I want to start docker multicontainer on Elastic Beanstalk (EBS) with couldformation.

From what I understood from this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun_format) is that I have create docker images. Push it to ECR. Then create a `Dockerrun.aws.json` at the root of my project. Then link the ECR path in the `Dorckerrun.aws.json` file. ...and that's it?

So I created the docker images and pushed it to ECR. I also created the `Dockerrun.aws.json` with the corresponding values (some I'm not quite sure... e.g. what is the difference between `mountPoints` and `host.sourcePath`).

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "myApplication1",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/myApplication1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myApplication2",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/myApplication2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myApplication3",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/myApplication3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "myApplication1",
      "image": "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myDocker/myApplication1",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "????",
          "containerPath": "????",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-myApplication1",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/myApplication1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "myApplication2",
      "image": "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myDocker/myApplication2",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "myApplication1", "myApplication3"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "????",
          "containerPath": "????",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "?????",
          "containerPath": "????",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-myApplication2",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/myApplication2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "myApplication3",
      "image": "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myDocker/myApplication3",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "?????",
          "containerPath": "?????",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-myApplication3",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/myApplication3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I was wondering how to start it in cloudformation? My assumption is that I have to define EBS in cloudformation template (yaml) and reference the resource `Dockerrun.aws.json` somewhere. If so, how? I haven't found a template for that purpose (only for single docker container).

Answer (score 0):

> Volumes on the instance 
>   Creates volumes from folders in the Amazon EC2 container instance, or from your source bundle
>   (deployed to /var/app/current). Mount these volumes to paths within your Docker containers using mountPoints in the container definition.

Mount is the docker mount of the Volume on the ec2 host.

> Volumes from the Amazon EC2 container instance to mount, and 
>   the location on the Docker container file system at which to mount them. 
>   When you mount volumes that contain application content, your container can read 
>   the data you upload in your source bundle. When you mount log volumes for writing 
>   log data, Elastic Beanstalk can gather log data from these volumes.

For Cloud formation you need to create the following.

ElasticBeanstalk Environment

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
   "Properties" : {
      "ApplicationName" : String,
      "CNAMEPrefix" : String,
      "Description" :  String,
      "EnvironmentName" :  String,
      "OptionSettings" : [ OptionSetting, ... ],
      "PlatformArn" : String,
      "SolutionStackName" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
      "TemplateName" : String,
      "Tier" : Environment Tier,
      "VersionLabel" : String
   }
}
```

Docker platforms
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.docker

ElasticBeanstalk Application

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
   "Properties" : {
      "ApplicationName" : String,
      "Description" : String,
      "ResourceLifecycleConfig" : ApplicationResourceLifecycleConfig

   }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk.html

ElasticBeanstalk Application Version

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion",
  "Properties" : {
    "ApplicationName" : String,
    "Description" : String,
    "SourceBundle" : { SourceBundle }
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-version.html

You can upload your application code and the Docker run.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-sourcebundle.html

ElasticBeanstalk ConfigurationTemplate

```
{
  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
      "Properties" : {  
        "ApplicationName" : String,
        "Description" : String,
        "EnvironmentId" : String,
        "OptionSettings" : [ ConfigurationOptionSetting, ... ],
        "PlatformArn" : String,
        "SolutionStackName" : String,
        "SourceConfiguration" : SourceConfiguration
      } 
    }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html